# Using Assert module in node, outside of testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert

I have a question about the Assert module in nodejs.

Is it good practice to use the Assert module outside of "Testing", I mean in production, like
if I have a function to sum two numbers, can I use Assert module, to check those
two parameters are they number or not

This is just simple example, but you can understand the point

Will this affect code execution or speed or something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use a validator like Joi?

Comment: I didn't mean just for params, but for another part of the code, but yeah I use Joi for validating params

Comment: Yes, it's good practice to keep invariant checks in the code, as especially in production you will want to know when they were broken. That might mean using the `assert` module, or any other logic. And yes, of course executing those checks takes more time than not executing them - but only you can (measure and) decide whether it's worth it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally you don't use debugging tools in development. In fact, you don't even put it in your actual code but create a separate (unit) testing environment. Because of this, I'd definitely not consider doing that.

The assert module as I understand actually terminates the program and displays an error message and stack trace on failure, which is probably not what you want in an actual production environment.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I needed :)

Comment: Cheers! ;) I'd appreciate if you marked it correct and then we can close the case

Comment: "*The assert module as I understand actually terminates the program*" - no, it doesn't, it just throws an `AssertionError`.

Comment: Does that make this answer mute then? I'd actually like to know this as well. Because, for example, it'd be useful to have a comparison function for object equality in production code.